# Was sind Leuteranten?

Tags: meaning

Jean Paul, das alte Scheusal, bringt mich um den Schlaf! Ich dachte schon, bei diesem - weder in Grimm noch im DWDS oder im Frühneuhochdeutschen Wörterbuch verzeichneten - Begriffe, müsse es sich um eine von Pauls exzentrischen Wortschöpfungen handeln, doch sprechen dagegen die zahlreichen Google-[Treffer](https://www.google.at/search?q=Leuteranten&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari) in rechtsbezogenen Texten des 17. und 18. Jahrhunderts.

Was, bei unserer Lieben Frau, sind also Leuteranten?!

---

Die ursprüngliche Fundstelle im „[Siebenkäs](https://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/siebenkas-3215/4)“ lautet:

> Mit dem Löffel und der Gabel in der Hand und vor dem Tischgebet war er noch zu dauerhaftem Schlaf untüchtig; ich ergötzte ihn also mit muntern Sachen von Belang, mit dem erschossnen unausgeweideten Passagier (dem obigen Rehkalb) – mit einigen kleinen Krämer-Falliments unterweges – mit meinen Gedanken über den Frankreichischen Krieg und mit der Beteuerung, die Friedrichstraße in Berlin sei eine halbe Meile lang und die dasige Preß- und Handelsfreiheit groß – auch merkt' ich an, daß ich durch wenige deutsche Kreise gefahren sei, worin nicht die Betteljungen noch als die Revisionräte und Leuteranten der Zeitungschreiber dienten

Comment: Vlt. Leute, die geläutert sind/wurden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sucht man die entsprechende Textstelle findet man rasch die Ausgabe "Deutsche National-Litteratur: historisch kritische Ausgabe, Band 131, Teil 1"

Der Abschnitt befindet sich auf [Seite 196](https://books.google.de/books?id=0Ws6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=leuteranten&source=bl&ots=6SaKcYf9oh&sig=ACfU3U00afp5C6RmHrKLTqrGYocqUnAMfQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz5KrzxvrkAhUJPFAKHXkgBB0Q6AEwDXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=leuteranten%20&f=false) und in der Fußnote der Seite steht:

> Leuterant heißt derjenige, welcher ein Sach- und Rechtsverhältnis vor demselben Richter nochmals erläutert, der ihm soeben ein ungünstiges Urteil gesprochen.

Comment: "Berufung" wäre ein Begriff, der mir hier fehlt.

Answer (score 4):

Ich habe die Wurzel und vielleicht auch die Bedeutung! Im Grimm steht mit anderer Orthographie:

> LÄUTERIEREN, verb. für läutern im juristischen sinne hat sich seit dem 17. jh. barbarisch herausgebildet: ein urteil zu leutern, sive leuteriren, ulteriorem sententiam petere, leuterationem interponere Stieler 1095, mit leuterant, leuterans, seu provocans a sententia ad ulteriorem deductionem, und leuterat, leuteratus, altera pars, quae ad istam deductionem leuterantis respondere tenetur. vgl. DWB läutern 4.

Jetzt hatte ich leider nur Griechisch und kein Latein, aber ich interpretiere „ulteriorem sententiam petere“ als „um ein weiteres Urteil ersuchen“! Es wäre dann der Leuterant ein Kläger in einem weiterführenden Gerichtsprozesse. Versteht es jemand noch besser?

Bei „LÄUTERN“, auf das verwiesen wurde, steht im Grimm noch:

> 4) läutern, in der juristischen sprache, einen richterspruch oder eine entscheidung an die höhere instanz ziehen, auf dasz er erläutert oder verbessert werde